# nltk.stem has no attribute "Stemmer"

Tags: python

I am working on code from a team-member. I have to use python2.

`import Stemmer` is called at the top of the script. However, I was getting the error `No module named Stemmer`.

Per [python, Stemmer not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49634536/python-stemmer-not-found), I changed the line to `import nltk.stem as Stemmer`. However, now the script crashed at the line `stemmer   = Stemmer.Stemmer('english')`, giving me the error `'module' object has no attribute 'Stemmer'`.

I think `Stemmer` might be part of the module `pyStemmer`, but when I try to install `pyStemmer` through  `python -m pip install pyStemmer` or `python -m pip install pyStemmer==1.3.0` I get a bunch of indecipherable errors.

Any suggestions on how to proceed? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I couldn't install `pyStemmer` was because I did not have `Cython` installed. See [this github issue](https://github.com/snowballstem/pystemmer/issues/28). Once I installed `Cython`, I was able to install `pyStemmer` and my code ran smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I come across the same question and it was solved by following steps:

```
from nltk.stem import *
from nltk.stem.porter import *
stemmer = PorterStemmer()
```